# How is the word "from" used in these phrases?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Please help in understanding these types of phrases:

1. He did it from gratitude.

Why is the preposition 'from' used here? Why not 'with'?

2. The knights were brave from gallantry of spirit.

What does it mean?

Comment: Have you looked up *from* and *with* in dictionaries, read the definitions and looked at the example sentences? This site requests that you include the research you've done as part of your question.

Comment: R H K Webster's  usage7 _(used to indicate cause or reason)_ is the best match I found at [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/from).

Comment: "From" means, roughly, "caused by" in those examples.

Comment: It's a spatial metaphor: *from* indicates that the gratitude is the *source* of the action, the sentiment "from which" the action sprang; *with* would indicate that the gratitude *accompanied* the action, became evident "with" the action.

Comment: Really thanks .. but what does the other sentence literally mean? " The knights were brave from gallantry of spirit"??

Comment: Welcome to our site. I’m afraid that as it stands, this question is too basic for [english.se], as it can be easily answered by checking the respective definitions of those two words and their varying usage patterns in any decent dictionary. If you haven’t yet explored our sister-site for [ell.se], you might check it out. If you after looking at dictionary definitions and examples you find that your question has not been answered by them, you can edit your question to include what you found and why that didn’t answer your question; that will nominates your question to be re-opened.

Comment: @tchrist - I would add one thing: if the OP decides to ask this question on [ell.se], I hope there will be more information about where these sentences came from. Take this sentence: _The knights were brave from gallantry of spirit._ It's hard to answer questions like, "What does this mean?" or "Why is it worded that way?" when we have no idea who wrote it, in what context, or when it was written – sometimes we need to know if it's a sentence from an established author, or some random sentence off an internet discussion board.

Comment: Thank you very much . Actually, I am not an English native speaker , I am learning the language and I really did the research on these sentences but I didn't get it..                  I got these sentences from the 'Wren n martin , English grammar book in the usage of 'prepostion'. Preposition always confuses me...

Answer (score 1):

"from" indicates cause in those sentences. "out of" would be more common than "from" in those sentences.

"with" would indicate manner in the first sentence, and wouldn't work in the second one.

Comment: You are quite right that "out of" would be more common - indeed better in my view. However my own way of saying it would be that "his doing it was informed by gratitude".